# Qual a difença entre usar "tab <- html_table(tabela)[[1]]" ou "tab <- html_table(tabela)" do pacote rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/superbowl/history/winners'
pagina <- read_html(url)
tabela <- html_nodes(pagina, 'table')
tab <- html_table(tabela)[[1]]
```

O código acima funciona do jeito esperado e esse, abaixo, não:

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/superbowl/history/winners'
pagina <- read_html(url)
tabela <- html_nodes(pagina, 'table')
tab <- html_table(tabela)
```

Eu não entendi o que faz o `[[1]]` na função.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O resultado da função `html_table` é uma lista:

```r
library(rvest)

url <- 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/superbowl/history/winners'
pagina <- read_html(url)
tabela <- html_nodes(pagina, 'table')
tab <- html_table(tabela)

is.data.frame(tab)
#> [1] FALSE

is.list(tab)
#> [1] TRUE

length(tab)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Quando a função é aplicada em uma página com uma ou mais tabelas, cada tabela da página se torna um data frame, e cada data frame é um elemento dessa lista. Assim, para acessar alguma dessas tabelas individualmente, é necessário informar ao R qual tabela é desejada. No teu caso, o interesse está na primeira (e única) tabela presente na página. Portanto, o `[[1]]` é usado como indexador, de modo a obter o data frame que contém a tabela com os vencedores do Super Bowl:

```r
library(rvest)

url <- 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/superbowl/history/winners'
pagina <- read_html(url)
tabela <- html_nodes(pagina, 'table')
tab <- html_table(tabela)[[1]]

is.data.frame(tab)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Agora faz sentido!! 